# Converting string to boolean dynamically

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a following code snippet for KendoUI

```
{
    width: 90,
    field: "StatusDesc",
    title: i18n.t("FirmwareTranslation:Columns.StatusDesc"),
    filterable: dynFilter
}
```

I have to change the value of fiterable attribute dynamically.
Its based on a condition like if data present in Grid then i will show this filter option for that particular column else not.

So here what i am doing

declare a new variable globally , `var dynFilter`.

Now if data is not  present i am setting it as `false` which is working as expected  else setting it as `dynFilter="{multi:true}"` . But boolean variable true is not working since it is a part of string.

Now i want to set this variable in such a way that it should take true as a parameter for multi.i mean in the whole string "{multi:true}" true will be as boolean and rest as string .

Can anyone please explain how do i achieve this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understanding correctly, no need to set it as string.

```
var dynFilter;
dynFilter="{multi:true}";   // Won't work
alert (dynFilter['multi']); // Undefined

dynFilter={multi:true};     // Will work
if (dynFilter['multi']) 
    alert('multi is true'); 
else
    alert('multi is false');
```